# Git - fatal: Unable to create '/path/my_project/.git/index.lock': No such file or directory read tree xxxx command returned error: 128

Tags: bitbucket, git-svn

I'm converting my SVN repo into git (bitbucket) following this tutorial: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/migrating-convert/

But I keep getting this message when runing the command : git svn clone --stdlayout --authors-file=authors.txt --prefix=origin/

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Does this solution help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13457910/git-svn-importing-a-branch-with-a-trailing-space

Comment: Yes, thanks.  I found that later that day and solved the problem.  Wish I could cancel my bounty. :)

Comment: Thank you for the bounty..:-)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is somewhat explained in the comment.

> Similar issues are experienced on Windows system due to its
>   limitations like:

- Some of the Windows APIs are limited to `260 symbols` for file path name. So git can't create files with names longer than 260 symbols. `NTFS` file system actually supports longer names `(32k)`.
- Windows directory allows Space in between like `my folder`.
- Windows file and folder names that begin or end with the `ASCII Space (0x20)` are saved without these characters.

> Some of the Workarounds are:

- Move the `git` directory closer to the drive, in order to keep the file name within 260 symbols.
- Creating the `whitespace` directory manually using tools like `FAR`, `GnuWin`which can make a directory

Reference:

- [Support for Whitespace characters in File and Folder](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2829981)
- [git svn importing a branch with a trailing space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13457910/git-svn-importing-a-branch-with-a-trailing-space)
- [git checkout error: unable to create file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811991/git-checkout-error-unable-to-create-file)