# Git Svn Command Errors On Svn Tag Containing A Trailing Space

Tags: linux, git, github, svn, git-svn

I've inherited a Subversion (SVN) repository with 10 years of history, but when I am trying to convert to GitHub using `git svn` command, although the following command is running perfectly, I am still getting an error:

Currently `version 2.38.1` (windows)

**Error**

```
$ git svn fetch

Found possible branch point: https://REDACTED/tags/REDACTED%20Rev%20D => https://REDACTED/tags/REDACTED%20REV%20D%20, 4255
Found branch parent: (refs/remotes/origin/tags/REDACTED Rev D ) 6900fc84b93ff8d331aae85af70b5afdc333f6f0`
fatal: Unable to create 'C:/SrcRoot/REDACTED/.git/svn/refs/remotes/origin/tags/REDACTED Rev D /index.lock': Invalid argument
read-tree 6900fc84b93ff8d331aae85af70b5afdc333f6f0: command returned error: 128
```

There's a trailing space in the svn tag folder, that was removed a few moths later. It looks like the git svn fetch command is failing to process the tag folder name properly due to the trailing space.

Is there any way to make git svn fetch skip that tag?

Related issues: [Git svn importing a branch with a trailing space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13457910/git-svn-importing-a-branch-with-a-trailing-space)

**Directory**

This the my current directory, but with this tag is being created with a trailing space,  and the suggestions in that question don't seem to apply.

```
...\.git\svn\refs\remotes\origin\tags
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/11365319/960558

Comment: @lazy-badger The accepted answer for [git-svn clone fails "fatal: Not a valid object name"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11365319/960558) says to rename the tag directory in .git/refs/remotes/tags/ to include the space.  In my case, the directory is created with a space, so I don't think it applies.  None of the other suggestions there helped, either.

Comment: There may be some way to fix the tag within SVN, but if not, consider doing the conversion on a Linux system. You can set one up as a VM within your Windows system if you like.